# Execute SQLPlus sql file in relative path in ShellScript

Tags: sql, shell, sqlplus, oracle-xe

I'm trying to create a ShellScript whicht connect sqlplus and execute a file.sql in subfolder.

```
- folderA/
 * scripts/myShellScript.sh
 * sql/mySql.sql
```

I wanted to execute mySql.sql from myShellScript.sh.

I tried this:

```
@../sql/mySql.sql
```

But its return: file not found.

This its my code:

```
sqlplus -s $username/$password > logtest << EOF
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;

set echo on
set time off
set timing off
set heading off
set termout off
prompt ...
@../mySql.sql

SPOOL OFF
exit;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The path after `@` is relative to the path `myShellScript.sh` is called from, not to the path `myShellScript.sh` resides in.

If you `cd` into `folderA/scripts/` and run `./myShellScript.sh` referring to the SQL file as `@../sql/mySql.sql` it should work just fine.

If, instead, you are invoking `myShellScript.sh` from `folderA/` as `./scripts/myShellScript.sh` you will have to use `@./sql/mySql.sql`.

A possible way to call `myShellScript.sh` from an arbitrary location would be to add some handling of the current directory in the script:

```sh
cd "${0%/*}"
sqlplus -s $username/$password > logtest << EOF
...
@../sql/mySql.sql
```

This way, `sqlplus` is run from the path `myShellScript.sh` resides in.
But, of course, this will also alter the path `logtest` is written to.

Actually, the most common approach I have seen is to specify all paths as absolute and hold them in variables:

```sh
sqlpath=/path/to/sql/files
logpath=/path/to/logs

sqlplus USER/PASSWD >"$logpath"/logtest @"$sqlpath"/mySql.sql
```